# Copy text from rectangle selection in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

A picture is worth a thousand words :

[image: rietveld ux]

In [Rietveld](https://code.google.com/p/rietveld/) web diff tool I want to copy code from one of the buffer, but text selection with the mouse spreads over the other buffer when selecting multiple lines.

I wish I could draw a rectangle on screen and all text contained in that bounding box be pasted in my clipboard. Is there an extension for that ?

**Edit:**

Here is the kind of result I'd like to achieve, say I want to copy the right buffer :

[image]

Comment: I can copy text just fine.

Comment: @davidenko cool, me too! I added an image of the expected result. If you achieve that, please share how you're doing as it is not default chrome behaviour.

Comment: seems like a similar issue to using screen or tmux with Firessh

Comment: My apologies @kraymer I misunderstood the question and understood it after you edited the question. But I've found some interesting extensions: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/copy-and-paste-multiple-i/lhmhioddheplnfnchhnjpdcbnmkiandj , https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/savemyclips/inbmbkfkikgfjcjhgkoofielljhoipfe , https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clipper/ocjggicfjgaiiiiddogmikmeaplmkegg and https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/columncopy/lapbbfoohlcmlbdaakldmmallcbcbpjb

Comment: Are those columns defined as HTML table elements by any chance?

Comment: from all the extensions cited, only 'columncopy' is related to my problem but works only for html tables which is not the case here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content you wish to separate is wrapped in a table.

If you copy/paste it into a [google sheets](https://sheets.google.com/) document, you will get the left and right side on separate columns, and can simply mark one of them to copy it's content into the text editor of your choice.

Here's a working [example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WmG7TZdcoqNqH4b3l7AxfGx3qZurIAN7-yIdqBk2ic8/edit?usp=sharing) (make a copy of the sheet and change the URL in D2 to load another page)

I hope it helps.